# VSCode Python debugging step back/review history

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

How can I set a conditional breakpoint in VSCode Python, then step back n lines to see how that condition was met?

Comment: Not exactly sure if what your asking is what you want?   VS code does not have a replay capability that I am aware of.   when the breakpoint is hit you have the state of the variables and the call stack.   you can click up the call stack and see the vars that fed into the call you broke within.

Comment: @LhasaDad Thank you, but my bug occurs in a loop so I cannot access the previous loop iterations from the call stack.
If not in VS Code, is there another debugger I can use which has replay capability?

Comment: @LhasaDad I did a search and found a debugger called PyTrace. Thanks for putting me on the right wording to search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need something like PyTrace.   It allows you to debug and replay/rewind the state of the interpreter to see how you got to your breakpoint.  https://pytrace.com/